# How to fix [Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "id" when navigating

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use VueJS 3.3 and Vue Router v4.

have the following route structure.

[image]

Vue keeps complaining:

`[Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "id" when navigating.`

I've read that if I push artificial parameters when redirecting, it will give me the error. But I'm hitting the exact URL. No `router.push` or anything.

Here is what the part of my router responsible for the URL looks like.

[image]

My URL is

http://localhost:5173/koin/document-sets/177/comments

Where 177 is "documentSetId" param.

I tried replacing

`props: route => ({ documentSetId: parseInt(route.params.documentSetId as string) })`

with `props: true`, without any success.

But the whole app works. And there is even no :id param in this exact URL. I checked the whole route tree, and the URLs /koin/document-sets/:documentSetId/comments, doesn't have :id param anywhere.

Why VueJS complains?

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you find out a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

- Putting the data in a store like [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/): this is relevant if the
  data is used across multiple pages
- Move the data to an actual param by defining it on the route's path
  or pass it as **query** params: this is relevant if you have small pieces
  of data that can fit in the URL and should be preserved when
  reloading the page
- Pass the data as state to save it to the [History API state](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routelocationoptions.html#state):

  ```
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'somewhere', state: { myData } }">...</router-link>
  <button
    @click="$router.push({ name: 'somewhere', state: { myData } })"
  >...</button>
  ```

  Note state is subject to History state limitations.
- Pass it as a new property to to.meta during navigation guards:

  ```
  router.beforeEach(async to => {
    if (to.meta.shouldFetch) {
      // name `data` whatever you want
      to.meta.data = await fetchSomething()
    }
  })
  ```

  This is known an transient state and since it's in a navigation
  guard, it will be preserved when reloading the page. [Check the
  documentation for more details.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#typescript)
- [click here for the Reference](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22)